# how uiview in ScrollView offset sync?

Tags: ios, scrollview, offset

I am implementing uiview in scrollview. 
If uiview is selected, uiview position of scrollviewd is changed. 
Help me

code

```
itemContentView.itemIndex = [@(i) stringValue];
itemContentView.frame = CGRectMake((i * _scrollView.frame.size.width) + (i * cellSpace), 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height);

_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((_scrollView.frame.size.width * [pageViewArray count]) + (cellSpace * [pageViewArray count]), _scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

delegate

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    float pageWidth = cellWidth + (cellSpace * 2); // width + space

    float currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    float targetOffset = targetContentOffset->x;
    float newTargetOffset = 0;

    if (targetOffset > currentOffset)
        newTargetOffset = ceilf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth;
    else
        newTargetOffset = floorf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth;

    if (newTargetOffset < 0)
        newTargetOffset = 0;
    else if (newTargetOffset > scrollView.contentSize.width)
        newTargetOffset = scrollView.contentSize.width;

    targetContentOffset->x = currentOffset;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newTargetOffset, 0) animated:YES];

    int index = newTargetOffset / pageWidth;

    if (index >= 0 && index < [_pageViewArray count]) {
        self.pageIndex = index;
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkTeu.png)

i don't know why.. offset changed..

my sample source code
https://github.com/ToniKroos/ScrollView

Comment: I will shot this but could it be this line?  
   
itemView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, self.view.bounds.size.width, 281);

At controller

Comment: itemView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, self.view.bounds.size.width, 281); this code what's your meen?

Comment: i settle. scrollview set property padding enabled false

Answer (score 0):

i mean.. how click a button on specific uiview scrolling enable false?

Look at the third image. click a close button. why occurs scrolling event

i don't know 4th image result.

case step

1
http:// i.imgur.com/pj3VTCb.png

2 http:// i.imgur.com/S6LIPQW.png

3 http:// i.imgur.com/EykVXJP.png

4 http:// i.imgur.com/gwxJqLd.png